# How do I get the featured image to sit below the header in the twenty nineteen theme?

Tags: themes, post-thumbnails, headers

In the twentynineteen theme, the featured image in a post becomes the background of the post. Actually, it becomes the background of the header. I'm trying to get it sit below the header in each post as in the default front page.

What is the minimum lines I need to change to make this happen?

Here is the relevant portion of header.php....

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<div id="page" class="site">
    <a class="skip-link screen-reader-text" href="#content"><?php _e( 'Skip to content', 'twentynineteen' ); ?></a>

        <header id="masthead" class="<?php echo is_singular() && twentynineteen_can_show_post_thumbnail() ? 'site-header featured-image' : 'site-header'; ?>">

            <div class="site-branding-container">
                <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/header/site', 'branding' ); ?>
            </div><!-- .layout-wrap -->

            <?php if ( is_singular() && twentynineteen_can_show_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
                <div class="site-featured-image">
                    <?php
                        twentynineteen_post_thumbnail();
                        the_post();
                        $discussion = ! is_page() && twentynineteen_can_show_post_thumbnail() ? twentynineteen_get_discussion_data() : null;

                        $classes = 'entry-header';
                        if ( ! empty( $discussion ) && absint( $discussion->responses ) > 0 ) {
                            $classes = 'entry-header has-discussion';
                        }
                    ?>
                    <div class="<?php echo $classes; ?>">
                        <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/header/entry', 'header' ); ?>
                    </div><!-- .entry-header -->
                    <?php rewind_posts(); ?>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </header><!-- #masthead -->

    <div id="content" class="site-content">
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a filter to your functions.php theme: `add_filter('twentynineteen_can_show_post_thumbnail', '__return_false');`